# Select or Unselect jquery in radio button for different <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello everyone i design a page for signup panel 
here in this page i use radio button with label in different different li with different value. my design is

```
<div class="usertype">
    <ul>
        <li id="bathroomslct"><label>Bathrooms:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Bathrooms" value="1" id="Bathrooms1" /><label class="new-label" for="Bathrooms1">1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Bathrooms" value="2" id="Bathrooms2" /><label class="new-label" for="Bathrooms2">2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Bathrooms" value="3" id="Bathrooms3" /><label class="new-label" for="Bathrooms3">3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Bathrooms" value="4" id="Bathrooms4" /><label class="new-label" for="Bathrooms4">4</label>
        </li>
        <li> <label>Furnished</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Furnished" value="Unfurnished" id="Unfurnished" /><label class="new-label" for="Unfurnished">Unfurnished</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Furnished" value="Semifurnished" id="Semifurnished" /><label class="new-label" for="Semifurnished">Semifurnished</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Furnished" value="Furnished" id="Furnished" /><label class="new-label" for="Furnished">Furnished</label>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

here i'm using this script for select radio button

```
    <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
    $(".usertype ul li#bathroomslct label.new-label label").click(function () {
        $(".usertype ul li#bathroomslct label.new-label label").not(this).removeClass("selected").addClass('unselected')
        $(this).toggleClass("unselected").toggleClass("selected");
    });
    });
</script>
```

so how i fix my problem 
radio not selected for different li..

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do with http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dGzG9/1/

Comment: radio button is select but i want to change the background color of my label

Comment: for example when i select radio button of bathrooms like 1 then background color of 1 is change and when i select Furnished then also background also change for this

Comment: i use background in label with class selected or class unselected

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F2DMs/37/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".usertype li .new-label, .usertype li input").click(function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.tagName);
        if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
            $(this).next("label").addClass("selected").removeClass("unselected")
            .siblings(".new-label").addClass("unselected").removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Since you're using the `for="..."` attribute on your labels, the click event fires twice when you click a label. You need to catch only the `input` clicks.

You might also want to add the `selected` and `unselected` classes to your elements from the start as well.

**EDIT**
Just noticed you wanted the background-color to change, so I updated that in the demo

Comment: That's probably because you have `$(window).load` and I have `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your jQuery selector is wrong. Change

```
$(".usertype ul li#bathroomslct label.new-label label")
```

Into

```
$(".usertype ul li#bathroomslct label.new-label")
```

Comment: [It should work](http://jsbin.com/lecew/1). Check to make sure you have include jQuery before this script. Another note is that in your version, this only work when you click on the **label** (not the radio button).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.usertype li input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        var $next = $(this).next().removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
        $(this).siblings('.new-label').not($next).removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dGzG9/)

Comment: here Unfurnished, Semifurnished color not changed 
i want change color of both

Comment: but its not working in my page i think i need a jquery plugin like jQuery 1.11.0 or not?

Comment: you need to include jQuery in your page... have you done that... is there any error in your browser console

Comment: which jQuery i use please tell me

Comment: from where i download it please

Comment: @user2930603 http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js ... or use a CDN version like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>`